# Solving basic PDE with the method of characteristic.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My attempt:

Given $$(x^{2}-y^{2})\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2xy\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =0$$
    By the method of characteristic, we have $$\frac{dx}{x^{2}-y^{2}} =\frac{dy}{2xy}=dt\Rightarrow\int2xydx=\int(x^{2}-y^{2})dy\Rightarrow x^{2}y=x^{2}y-\frac{1}{3}y^{3}+c\Rightarrow y^{3}=c'$$
    for some constant $c'$.Hence, the general solution is $u=f(y^{3})$ for some differentiable function $f$.

But I was told that this is incorrect. I'm having trouble understanding where I messed up.

Comment: $d(x^2y)=2xydx+x^2dy$

Comment: @dmtri I can see that. However, I'm not sure how I can go about correcting my mistake.

Comment: Why the antiderivative of $2xydx$ is $x^2y$?

Comment: @dmtri I see! $\int 2xydx= x^2y+2x\int y dx$ But here, how do I know what $\int ydx$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of characteristic reduces a PDE problem into an ODE problem, in this case to the ODE $\frac{dx}{x^2-y^2} = \frac{dy}{2xy}$ as you identified. Writing this in the form $2xy\ dx + (y^2-x^2)\ dy = 0$, we notice that this is homogenous and so can be solved by substituting $x = uy, dx = udy + ydu$ to get
$$2uy^2(udy + ydu) + y^2(1-u^2)dy = 0 \implies 2uy^3du + y^2(1+u^2)dy,$$
giving us the separable equation
$$\frac{2u}{1+u^2}du + \frac{1}{y}dy = 0$$
which can be solved by integrating the terms independently. The strategy you used did not work because the equation was not separated, so integration is not an effective solution method.

Comment: Why do I need to substitute $x=uy$? where did that quation come from?

Comment: This is the standard substitution when a differential equation of the form $P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy$ is homogenous in order to make it separable. A homogenous equation of order $n$ means that $P(tx,ty) = t^nP(x,y)$, and similarly for $Q$, for any real number $t$. If this is the case, one can see how substituting $x = uy$ (or $y=ux$) may lead to a separable equation due to the homogenous property (in fact you can prove this is always the case). Notice that for this problem, the equation is homogenous of order 2.